# How to convert table name to uppercase using JDBC sink connector

Tags: oracle, jdbc, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform, debezium

I am implementing CDC based replication between Postgres and Oracle databases. For the source connector I am using Debezium's Postgres Connector and for the sink connector Confluent's JDBC Sink Connector.

In the Postgres database, all tables are created in lowercase, but in the Oracle database tables are in uppercase. How can I dynamically set config in the JDBC sink connector, so that I don't need to set a hardcoded uppercase table name in **transforms.route.replacement**? Currently if I don't set the destination table name in uppercase manually in the config, double quotes are being added by the connector. Then, I receive the following error:

> Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Table "TEST"."dummy_table" is missing and auto-creation is disabled

I have disabled auto-creation, because I don't need it.

Below is an example of my JDBC sink connector config. I have omitted some fields like connection url etc. If I leave the config like this, every time I need to add a new table, I would need to create a new JDBC sink connector.

```
{
    "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "topics": "test.public.dummy_table",
    "transforms": "route,unwrap",
    "transforms.route.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.RegexRouter",
    "transforms.route.regex": "([^.]+)\\.([^.]+)\\.([^.]+)",
    "transforms.route.replacement": "TEST.DUMMY_TABLE", // I want to use TEST.$3 here, but apply uppercase. Is it possible?
    "transforms.unwrap.drop.tombstones": "false",
    "transforms.unwrap.type": "io.debezium.transforms.ExtractNewRecordState",
    "value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
    "pk.mode": "record_key",
    "key.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
    "pk.fields": "id",
    "quote.sql.identifiers": "never"
}
```

Is it possible to achieve table name uppercase transformation using transforms.route.replacement or to tell the sink connector not to add double quotes? If not, could you please suggest how to implement it? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I thought `quote.sql.identifiers` fixed the quote problem...? But no, regex cannot apply case formatting

Comment: @OneCricketeer for some reason it removes the quote from the field names (columns), but not the table name. Am I missing any setting?

Comment: The description of that setting is _When to quote **table names**, column names, and other identifiers in SQL statements_. Sounds like could be a bug

Answer (score 0):

I know almost nothing about what you described.

**However**: as far as Oracle is concerned, table names are stored in uppercase in data dictionary, but Oracle lets you access them using any letter case you want (upper, lower, mixed):

```
SQL> select count(*) from emp union all       --> lower
  2  select count(*) from EMP union all       --> upper
  3  select count(*) from EmP;                --> mixed

  COUNT(*)
----------
        14
        14
        14

SQL>
```

That stands as long as you didn't use double quotes while creating the table; in that case, you must use the same letter case and enclose table name into double quotes every time you access it:

```
SQL> create table "teST" (id number);

Table created.

SQL> select * from test;
select * from test
              *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist


SQL> select * from TEST;
select * from TEST
              *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist


SQL> select * from teST;
select * from teST
              *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist


SQL> select * from "teST";

no rows selected

SQL>
```

So: if you weren't that unfortunate to use double quotes, perhaps you don't have to bother (as my first example shows). Just don't use double quotes while referencing the table and you're fine.

Comment: The problem is that JDBC sink connector adds double quotes around table names if they come in lowercase and I can't figure out how to tell not to do so.

Comment: Aha; oh well, shame on *JDBC sink connector* (whatever it is). Unfortunately, I don't know anything about it so I can't help, but I hope someone else will be able to assist. Good luck!

Comment: Yeah, I hope someone can help. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the problem with quotes in kafka connect sink, try setting quote_sql_identifiers to never.

https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connect-jdbc/current/sink-connector/index.html#jdbc-sink-identifier-quoting

Comment: Hi @wolvery, for some reason quote.sql.identifiers is not being applied to to table names. In my config it is set to never.